# How to make gaps between the browser window and the div disappear?

Tags: html, css

I created a div where I plan to a title for my webpage, I set the width to 100% but there was still white on the sides and top. I got the top to disappear but the sides won't, I assume it's got something to do with the movement of the div, I've checked everywhere, but everyone has different divs for different purposes so I couldn't find the answer. In case you guys wanna show an example of your solution you could do so [here](https://codepen.io/Filizof/pen/yReqvR?editors=1100)

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="toptitle">

</div>
```

For my CSS I tried using margin-left: -8px and the same for the right side but they don't work like that, it's only movement of the div and even when I don't set the left side yet the right still won't move till there's isn't a white gap:

```
#toptitle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    background: #42647F;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Comment: If you used the web inspector you would notice that the body element is applying a margin. Use always the web inspector, it makes the life easier

Answer (score 0):

Reset your body margin. Also make a research for reset css.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **margin: 0** to the body :

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing body margin, please have a look at the below working snippet taken from your codepen. and there is no need to have negative top margin too.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
#toptitle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  background: #42647F;
}
```

```html
<div id="toptitle">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `body` tag has a default margin of 8px which you have to remove. So just add this to your code:

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
```

You should also remove `margin-top:-15;`
Hope this is clear to you!